# How to upload two separate .aab files with different configuration on google play store?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, apk, bundle

I know a single app bundle is enough to support different kinds of configurations, but one of our module is in react native and recently we've upgraded the Gradle version to 7.0.0. due to which our build machine won't let us use the minimum SDK below 21. This is why I wanted to create separate .aab files(one created on the build machine the other one from android studio) with different API levels(one will support android 19+ and the other one will support android 21+) and I wanted to upload these bundles without changing package name or application id. Any suggestions around this? or is there any better way to do this?

Note:- Two separate .aab are a must. I already have looked into [this solution](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigating-your-way-around-customizable-delivery-e7a882390aa) but it is not helpful to me.